# ONT doesn't answer ARP request

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, mac-address, arp

I've been working with a custom linux image, based on yocto, running on an industrial tablet. During my tests, I've faced some problems to connect to a wifi network after rebooting the device.

Before rebooting, the wlan interface works properly and is listed by ifconfig command, like shown below:

```
lo    Link encap:Local Loopback
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:15182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:15182 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
      RX bytes:4832710 (4.6 MiB)  TX bytes:4832710 (4.6 MiB)

net0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr BE:DF:28:C7:9C:28
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING  MTU:900  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:823 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:281466 (274.8 KiB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr AC:83:F3:BE:F4:35
          inet addr:192.168.100.134  Bcast:192.168.100.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:400 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:1067 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:25731 (25.1 KiB)  TX bytes:109477 (106.9 KiB)
```

The arp table seems to be correctly filled

```
arp -a
? (192.168.100.1) at 58:f9:87:e4:b8:57 [ether]  on wlan0
? (192.168.100.8) at 98:83:89:93:79:db [ether]  on wlan0
```

I successfully pinged and accessed the device remotely via ssh.

However, after rebooting, the wlan interface still appears in ifconfig command, like the previous one, but when I try to ping or do ssh on the device, the following answer appears:

```
destination host unreachable
```

The following sentence appears a lot when the command "tcpdump -i wlan0" is run on the tablet terminal:

```
ARP, Request who-has 192.168.100.1 tell 192.168.100.134, length 28
```

According to my research, the arp request tries to solve the mac address of the device with the target ip. The address 192.168.100.1 corresponds to my ONT ip adddress, it seems that the network device doesn't answer the requests from my tablet.

The arp table has also changed:

```
? (192.168.100.1) at <incomplete> on wlan0
```

The connection only returns to its normal behavior after executing "ifdown wlan0 && ifup wlan0"

This behavior only happens with the tablet, other equipments connected in the same network don't face this situation.

Does someone know what's going on?

How can I establish a normal connection after rebooting the system?